# How can prot argument of mmap() syscall be 0x1007?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, shellcode

While analyzing Metasploit's linux/x64/shell/reverse_tcp payload, I realized it was using the value 0x1007 as the prot argument of the mmap() syscall.

The mmap() man page says that the prot argument is either PROT_NONE or the bitwise OR of one or more of the following flags: PROT_EXEC, PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE PROT_NONE. According to the /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mman.h file, the above mentioned flags have the values 0x4, 0x1, 0x2 and 0x0, respectively. How can this add up to 0x1007?

The syscall signature is:

void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);

The part of the code I was referring to is:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:

xor rdi,rdi                    
push byte +0x9                
pop rax                       
cdq                             
mov dh,0x10                    
mov rsi,rdx                     
xor r9,r9                       
push byte +0x22                
pop r10                        
mov dl,0x7                     
loadall286
```

Comment: The values you mention cover three bits: the kernel probably just ignores the values of any other bits.

Comment: The bit has no meaning for MMAP but if you review the code `cdq` sets _RDX_ to zero. then `mov dh,0x10` sets _DH_ to 0x10 which makes _RDX_ = 0x1000 (4096) which is used as the length parameter when _RDX_ is then copied to _RSI_. The fact it is set in the flag argument is of no consequence. The value 7 (lowest 3 bits on) are the bits the kernel knows about, and the kernel just ignored bits it doesn't care about. It isn't the way I would have done it.

Comment: When I compile and run this code it returns an address in _RAX_ which is what I'd expect (this comment is in response to an edit that has been reverted)

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes, I removed the edit after reading your comment, which clearly answered my question. I thought the edit was somewhat misleading. Once again, I cannot upvote your comment since I don't have enough rep. If you could provide an official answer, I would be happy to upvote.

Comment: You may self answer your own question - I don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @MichaelPetch, the most significant byte is ignored by the mmap() syscall. It only served to give a value to the length parameter by using the mov dh,0x10 and mov rsi,rdx instructions.